Various confusing compilation errors after updating Microsoft.IdentityModel libraries in ASP.Net Web Site
I have inherited some maintenance tasks on an older ASP.Net Web Site (not web project).  One of the tasks I'm working on is updating all vulnerable libraries.  This has been mostly smooth except for the Microsoft.IdentityModel libraries that are used for authentication.  Currently the application is on version 5.3.0 and I'm just trying to get it to 5.7.0, which is the latest fully patched version in the 5.x.x line.
After updating these packages to 5.7.0, either by NuGet or just manually copying DLLs, I start getting both intellisense and compiler errors.  Here is an example of the compiler output after updating to 5.7.0.  To get it back to a working state, I can just uninstall 5.7.0 and reinstall 5.3.0 with NuGet and it will work again.
C:\Code\Repos\webapp1\src\main-website\OrgSpecific\VENDOR1\VENDOR1_MainMasterPage.master(5): Build (web): Circular file references are not allowed.
C:\Code\Repos\webapp1\src\main-website\OrgSpecific\VENDOR1\VENDOR1_MainMasterPage.master(105): Build (web): Unknown server tag 'uc3:VENDOR1_footer'.
C:\Code\Repos\webapp1\src\main-website\MiscPages\OrganizationSelector.aspx(106): Build (web): Unknown server tag 'uc3:VENDOR1_footer'.
C:\Code\Repos\webapp1\src\main-website\Common\Controls\DataQualityValidationConfirmationButton.ascx(8,0): error BC30560: 'common_controls_yesnomodalpopup_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.
C:\Code\Repos\webapp1\src\main-website\Common\Controls\DataQualityValidationConfirmationButton.ascx(8,0): error BC30560: 'common_controls_yesnomodalpopup_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ca41222\b51c7e2a\App_Web_kqzcmgmk.6.vb(196,0): error BC30560: 'common_controls_yesnomodalpopup_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ca41222\b51c7e2a\App_Web_kqzcmgmk.6.vb(197,0): error BC30560: 'common_controls_yesnomodalpopup_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ca41222\b51c7e2a\App_Web_kqzcmgmk.6.vb(536,0): error BC30560: 'common_controls_yesnomodalpopup_ascx' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'.

Application/development information:

.Net Framework v4.8
VB.Net
ASP.Net Web Site (not web project)
Visual Studio 2019

Packages requiring update, but causing issues:

Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

Troubleshooting steps I've tried:

Deleting Temporary ASP.NET Files
Deleting intellisense cache (.suo file)
Deleting entire local project and redownloading from source control
Trying the same package update on another computer
Tried different package versions, at least one from nearly all versions of the IdentityModel from 5.4 to 8.0
Full rebuild (note: clean build is not an option on "Web Sites" template)
Checking web.config that assemblyBinding entries were correct version
Removing all web.config assemblyBinding entries
batch="false" on compilation tag in web.config

I'm out of ideas...
